# Jasper Report - Set Author property in a PDF document

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

Is there a way to set the Author property to a PDF document by setting a parameter when calling Jasper from Java.

[image]

This is how I generate a Jasper report from Java.

```
      JasperPrint jasperPrint;
        String outFile = "39285923953222.pdf";
        HashMap hm = new HashMap();
        hm.put("ID",id);
        hm.put("FOOTER",Constants.FOOTER); // Set somehow a string for the author name

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Connection con = session.connection();

        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperPath + "myReport.jasper", hm, con);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outPath + outFile);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at static field [**METADATA_AUTHOR**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterParameter.html#METADATA_AUTHOR) in [**JRPdfExporterParameter**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterParameter.html).

Use [**JRPdfExporter**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporter.html) instead of `JasperExportManager`.

Example :

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperPath + "myReport.jasper", hm, con);

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, outPath + outFile);
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.METADATA_AUTHOR, "Adnan");
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.METADATA_TITLE, "Title");
// ...
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Thank you @lschin, that is what I was looking for. Will try it out today.

Comment: Note that this has been deprecated in more recent versions, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117878/jasperreports-5-6-jrxlsexporter-setparameter-is-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the right way to go, but you might want to look at `jasperPrint.getPropertyNames()` or `jasperPrint.getPropertiesMap()` and see if you have any author property in there.

Answer (score 0):

JRExporter became deprecated in 5.6 according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117878/jasperreports-5-6-jrxlsexporter-setparameter-is-deprecated).
I got it to work doing this:

```
    ...
    final JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    final SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    configuration.setMetadataTitle(title);
    configuration.setMetadataAuthor(author);
    configuration.setMetadataCreator(creator);
    configuration.setMetadataSubject(subject);
    configuration.setMetadataKeywords(keywords);
    ...
```