# How to add custom properties to PDF document in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to put some custom properties into PDF document. Is possible to do that on [JRPdfExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporter.html) class or somewhere else (filler etc) ? I can't find this.

[image]

Update:
I found only [PdfStamper.setMoreInfo()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#setMoreInfo%28java.util.Map%29) method from `iText`. It works on exising pdf file only.

Comment: You can set only limited set of properties. You should look at [*JRPdfExporterParameter*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterParameter.html) class, it contains such fields as: [*METADATA_AUTHOR*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterParameter.html#METADATA_AUTHOR), *METADATA_CREATOR*, *METADATA_KEYWORDS* and so on. The sample of using on *SO*: [Jasper Report - Set Author property in a PDF document](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5552891/876298)