# JasperReports 5.6: JRXlsExporter.setParameter is deprecated

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export, deprecated

I have this code to export a JasperReprot to XLS:

```
        JasperPrint jprint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(expRpg, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(datalist));
        JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jprint); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outStream);
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporter.exportReport();
```

Upgrading to *JasperReports 5.6* all setParameter are flagged as "deprecated" and I can not find documentation to adapt this code.

How to export a report to xls with *JasperReports 5.6*?

Comment: You should read the [developers notice](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRAbstractExporter.html#setParameter%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter,%20java.lang.Object%29): `Replaced by setExporterInput(ExporterInput), setConfiguration(ExporterConfiguration), setConfiguration(ReportExportConfiguration) and setExporterOutput(ExporterOutput)`.

Comment: You can also find a lot of sample in *JR* package

Answer (score 75, accepted):

JRExporter became deprecated in 5.6. They introduced new interface Exporter and retrofitted all exporters to have ExporterInput, ReportExportConfiguration, ExporterConfiguration,ExporterOutput. See below link

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/Exporter.html

This means that instead of setParameter, you need to create configuration using above mentioned classes or their child classes
PDF export example. Excel export should follow same methodology

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(outputStream);
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

exporter.exportReport();
```

Excel counterpart

```
JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(destFile));
SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(true);
configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
configuration.setCollapseRowSpan(false);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

exporter.exportReport();
```

SimpleXlsReportConfiguration will have excel export related configuration. Set values as per your requirement

Comment: For the output stream, if you're using a class like `ByteArrayOutputStream` you should do this: `exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(os));`

Comment: a line "exporter.exportReport();" is missing for the excel counterpart

Comment: For `xlsx` (as opposed to `xls`) reports the corresponding configuration class is `SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration`

Answer (score 3):

Thank to the above code , here is my code : 
**Notice : Export excel with ireport, ireport 6.0 , java 7**

```
 Map<String, Object> parametro = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                parametro.put("USUARIO", UConstante.NAME_MINISTERIO_USER);
                parametro.put("RUTA_LOGO", PuenteFile.getRutaFiles(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), PuenteFile.RUTA_IMG_LOGO));
                parametro.put("PATH_SYSTEM", rutaFileSystemHD);
                parametro.put("WHERE_DATA", WHERE_REGISTRO);
                parametro.put("WHERE_PROYECTO_USUARIO", WHERE_PROYECTO_USUARIO);
                parametro.put("WHERE_ZONA", WHERE_ZONA);
                parametro.put("NAME_APP", RutaFile.NAME_APP);
                parametro.put("ID_USUARIO", getUsuario().getId());
                parametro.put("ID_PROYECTO", beanProyecto.getId());
                parametro.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", SUBREPORT_DIR);

                System.out.println(">>>>>> PARAMETROS :" + parametro.toString());

              try {
                    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path, parametro, PgConnector.getConexion());
                    JRXlsExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsExporter();
                    xlsExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
                    xlsExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(PuenteFile.getRutaFiles(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), PuenteFile.RUTA_REPORT_FILE) + nameExcel));
                    SimpleXlsReportConfiguration xlsReportConfiguration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
                    SimpleXlsExporterConfiguration xlsExporterConfiguration = new SimpleXlsExporterConfiguration();
                    xlsReportConfiguration.setOnePagePerSheet(true);
                    xlsReportConfiguration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(false);
                    xlsReportConfiguration.setDetectCellType(true);
                    xlsReportConfiguration.setWhitePageBackground(false);
                    xlsExporter.setConfiguration(xlsReportConfiguration);
                    xlsExporter.exportReport();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my CODE:

```
String sourceFileName = "./jasper_report_template.jasper";
Map parameters = new HashMap();
String printFileName = null;
try {
      printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(sourceFileName, parameters, beanArrayDataSource);
      if(printFileName != null){
           //JasperPrintManager.printReport( printFileName, true);
            /** 1- export to PDF*/
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printFileName,
                      "C://Users/zanderkong/Desktop/sample_report.pdf");
            /**3- export to Excel sheet*/
            RXlsExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsExporter();
            xlsExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(printFileName));
            xlsExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("C://Users/zanderkong/Desktop/sample_report.xls"));
            SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
            configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(true);
            configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
            configuration.setCollapseRowSpan(false);
            xlsExporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
            xlsExporter.exportReport();
         }
        } catch (JRException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
```